# IE 6 showing strange html output

Tags: xhtml, internet-explorer-6

so I have a been working on tweaking for IE 6 under Win 98 SE with virtualbox, and have come across this very strange behavior. There is additional text showing up at the footer even though the "View Source" shows nothing out of the `<a>` tag, the last 3 letters is coming up in the browser. Any idea what it could be? This only happens in IE 6.

[image]
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Although it is HTML5, I have used PHP to condition the DOCTYPE xhtml to be applied to IE6.

Also there is nothing to the right of line 209 anywhere. I've even changed the link display name and whatever is the last 3 chars, it will show up below the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Adding CSS style position:relative to the footer div fixed it. But I still don't know why it would append the last three ( if >= 3 chars) or the whole thing if the string is exactly three chars outside of the footer div, and would still act as though is the same link.

Anyone could care to explain what that is or if it's just some sort of known IE6 bug?